# ClickOnce 'not authorized to perform the current operation'

Tags: clickonce

I'm on a Linux server on the web
I use for some of the application I create clickonce deployment from Visual Studio 2010.
The webmaster just upgrade the system by installing suPHP.
Since they have enable suPHP I'm not able to update any existing deployment, but can create new one without any problem.

1. At the beginning I wasn't able to connect because FrontPage Extensions was disable so I reinstall it.
2. I am prompted to enter my login info, I do like always then press enter.
3. I am then re-prompted to enter my login info. This will continue indefinitely as long as I keep clicking OK.
4. Finally I give up and click Cancel, and then of course I get the error that I am 'not authorized to perform the current operation'.

It always work perfectly in the past and still does for the test application I did yesterday, but for all previous deployment it will give me the same error, it won't accept my login info.

I did check all folder permission on the server and are all OK
The folder were never moved and the same address in visual studio.

My question is do you have a solution for that or there is none except to redeploy to a new folder, that mean killing the update of thousands of users using the application until they re-install

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my problem but very unusual way to deal with the problem, but I will still like to know what really happen if one of the expert can answer, so here what I did

1. back up with ftp my application folder to application2
2. In visual studio I change the deployment link to application2
3. Then I publish the new update to that backup folder and work without any problem.
4. Rename the original folder to .back and rename application2 to the original name application.
5. open the already install program on my pc and did an update and was successful.
6. Now the last thing I needed to check was if I was able to publish a new update, did point the install url to is original deployment and work like a charm.

I hope that can be useful because I see many people with the same problem and answer are rare. But make sure to backup before attempting that